# How do I find in which (sub)sites a WebPart/Feature is used?

Tags: web-part, feature, governance

I need to find out on which (sub)sites a certain webpart is used. In a data sharing environment with many subsites and pages, I want to check if and where certain (third party) webparts are used. Is there a way to get a list of the locations where it is on the page?

Or more general: How do I find out where a feature is used? (For instance a site-template, when is it safe to uninstall it)

Comment: Thank you for sharing informative command. Quick question - How can I exclude the OOB? I wanted to find what ***custom*** webpart, eventreceiver, etc are in use. Thanks,
Khushi

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way to do get a quick view of what is being used where in a given content database is with the stsadm command [enumallwebs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793606%28office.12%29.aspx) using the addtional parameters supplied with the October 2009 Cumulative Update:

```
stsadm -o enumallwebs -includefeatures -includewebparts -includeeventreceivers -includesetupfiles -includecustomlistview
```

There's also a useful [MVP article](http://blog.brainlitter.com/archive/2010/05/18/sharepoint-2010-preupgradecheck-web-part-whack-a-mole.aspx) which is worth reading.

Comment: Wow, interesting, didn't know this, +1. I wonder if they have similar cmdlet for SharePoint?

Comment: Maybe my google-fu is down, but I couldn't find a technet reference to the 'new' options coming from the October 2009 CU.

Comment: And Thanks! Too bad our farm is still on SP2 (no extra CUs)

Comment: Don't think TechNet has caught up with this. For PowerShell I think you can do it by scripting the existing cmdlets and maybe a bit of object model, but may as well use stsadm for now.

Comment: You could take a backup and restore to a temporary SharePoint installation and install the CU there (DBAs permitting).

Answer (score 9):

You could do this through PowerShell. I used [this script](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/07/listing-all-web-parts-in-a-site-collection-with-powershell.html) as a basis and created the following script to list all webparts of all pages in all webs in a site collection. Take a look:

```
# Basis: http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/07/listing-all-web-parts-in-a-site-collection-with-powershell.html
# Modified by http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2509/tarjeieo
function EnumAllWebPartsOfSiteCollection($Url) {
    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $Url 
    $allFiles = @()
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
        Write-Host "Processing Web:" $web.Url -NoNewLine
        if ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($web)) {
            $pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
            $pages = $pWeb.PagesList

            foreach ($item in $pages.Items) {
                $allFiles += $item.File
            }
        }
        $pages = $null
        $pages = $web.Lists["Site Pages"]
        if ($pages) {
            foreach ($item in $pages.Items) {
                $allFiles += $item.File
            }
        }
        foreach ($file in $web.Files) {
            $allFiles += $file
        }
        $web.Dispose()
        Write-Host " - completed"
    }
    foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
        $fileUrl = $Url + $file.ServerRelativeUrl
        $manager = $file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);
        $wps = $manager.webparts
        $manager.Dispose()
        $wps | select-object @{Expression={$file.Web.Url};Label="Web URL"},@{Expression={$fileUrl};Label="Page URL"}, DisplayTitle, IsVisible, @{Expression={$_.GetType().ToString()};Label="Type"}
    }
    $site.Dispose()
}

$row = EnumAllWebPartsOfSiteCollection('http://test:1337')
$row | Out-GridView
```

Comment: This worked well for me since it includes all the web parts on non publishing / team sites as well which is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

For 2010, the Get-SPFeature cmdlet "Returns the SharePoint Features based on a given scope." But you still can use that enumallwebs command because PowerShell won't do all it does yet.