# How to determine what pages are using a particular web part?

Tags: web-part, 2010, administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find in which (sub)sites a WebPart/Feature is used?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12847/how-do-i-find-in-which-subsites-a-webpart-feature-is-used)

After an upgrade to SharePoint 2010, we've had a few web parts with issues.  We're a pretty wide ranging site (about 1TB worth of data/pages to comb through), is there an easy way to just get a report of any pages that make use of a particular web part so we can better inform users and/or warn of implemented fixes as we get them?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to [another question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12847/how-do-i-find-in-which-subsites-a-webpart-feature-is-used/12848#12848).

To recap, the best way to do get a quick view of what is being used where in a given content database is with the stsadm command [enumallwebs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793606%28office.12%29.aspx) using the addtional parameters (supplied with the October 2009 Cumulative Update, if you are using SP2007):

```
stsadm -o enumallwebs -includefeatures -includewebparts -includeeventreceivers -includesetupfiles -includecustomlistview
```

Comment: Do you think we should close this question as a duplicate instead of copying the answer over?

Comment: Yeah the situation is similar enough, move to close as dupe.  Sorry about that :-/

Comment: Haha you're on a roll @greg! Search man! Search!

Comment: I promise you I did Kit, the question was textually different enough to evade my own searches + the dupe checker while I'm typing in the question again.  I tell SharePoint people to get better search instead...