# Preupgrade check reveals webpart issues which are not installed on farm, how to identify the name, assembly of the referenced webparts

Tags: web-part, migration, upgrade

I have run a preupgrade check on a SP2007 database to identify issues prior to upgrading to SP2010. The report shows a lot of messages for missing webparts. The strange thing is that I cannot identify these webparts. The message looks like:

> WebPart class
>   [293e8d0e-486f-e21e-40e3-75bfb77202de]
>   is referenced [11695] times in the
>   database [sharepoint-3], but is not
>   installed on the current farm....

When I run a TEST-SPCONTENTDATABASE command on the SP2010 environment I get similar output. I have also downloaded the SP2007Migration.console.exe from CodePlex which takes the output of the TEST-SPCONTENTDATABASE from the SP2010 environment and runs that on the SP2007 environment to fetch all the sites/pages/webpart names etc.

Still the referenced web part issues relate to many sites and have a blank title. I have checked the sites to see if they have errors on the SP2007 environment but there are none. I have even mounted the database to SP2010 and after the migration the sites are looking fine. (So what are we talking about? haha)

**Question is**: what is the easiest way of identifying the webparts name, title, assembly etc as I have no clue where the issues are coming from. I need to know if I can safely ignore those like old references in the database which are perhaps from SP2003?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue [keeps cropping up](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12847/how-do-i-find-in-which-subsites-a-webpart-feature-is-used/12848#12848).

To recap, the best way to do get a quick view of what is being used where in a given content database is with the stsadm command [enumallwebs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793606%28office.12%29.aspx) using the addtional parameters (supplied with the October 2009 Cumulative Update, if you are using SP2007):

```
stsadm -o enumallwebs -includefeatures -includewebparts -includeeventreceivers -includesetupfiles -includecustomlistview
```

Comment: This is THE way to do it. The Guid cannot be used to backtrace the web part.

Comment: Yes, this works. Apologies for not having discovered the other issue earlier. So I can now see the Type of the webpart which is a default Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart. Keeps me puzzled as why preupgradechecker is referring oob web parts as 'not installed on farm'. Thanks @SPDoctor @Wictor-SharePoint-MVP

Comment: I used this and found the faulty webpart in the XML like this:
<WebPart Id="96868c1b-d534-790b-45ed-6c4f2fe6efa0" Count="1" Status="Missing" /> 
But now what? What can I do to correct this?